# iis like impersonation in apache

Tags: linux, apache, unix, iis, impersonation

I've been working with ASP.NET based applications hosted on IIS in past and I am well of aware of IIS internals and how it works.

Recently, I've switched to unix and now working with apache2 on RHEL 5. I've a small PoC type application where I need to impersonate the logged in user to access some files on server(which only logged in user has access). I know how to impersonate a user in IIS but not sure how (besy way?) to do similar thing in Apache. I recently learnt about suExec but not sure if that is a valid and secure option.

PS: the firewall is setup in such a way that I've the logged in user's details(except password) on the server side.

Any suggestions are deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could use cgi-bin. Set the owner of the executable to the user and set the suid bit for the executable.  This will make the executable run as the owner (user).  This will only work for normal users and not for root.